# Обработка исключений в конструкторах классов

Tags: c++

Какой смысл использовать try catch блок, где try находится перед списком инициализации конструктора, если в блоке catch мы все равно передадим исключение вверх?
Примерный код:

```
 class A{
 public: 
      A()
      try : obj(123){
      //...
      }catch(...){}
 private:
     SomeType obj;
 };

 int main(){
    A* obj;
    try{
         obj = new A; 
    }catch(...){}
 }
```

Смысл мне писать блок try catch для конструктора, если исключение в любом случае уйдет во внешний trycatch 
У меня есть только один вариант: trycatch для конструктора может передать вверх свой тип исключения, который мы захотим. Больше вариантов нет

Comment: Так не пишите, если смысла нет :) Может в самом обработчике ещё исключение выкидывается.

Comment: Если в обработчике выкидывается исключение, оно перекрывает то исключение, которое пришло в catch. Саттер пишет что назначение trycatch  для конструктора дано для того, чтобы выкидывать наверх исключение. Я не могу понять, зачем этот посредник

Comment: Ну да, можно выкинуть свое собственное исключение вместо исходного. Что тут неясного? Другой вопрос, как часто такое может понадобиться. В реальном коде я такого вообще никогда не видел.

Comment: Ну так тогда и может понадобиться это тогда, когда об ошибках нужно сообщить каким то однотипным образом

Answer (score 1):

Одним из вариантов использования такого "посредника" может быть сведение всех исключений, вылетающих из подклассов и не статических данных к единственному типу исключения:

```
class SomeTypeExp
{
    //...
};
template<typename ... Classes>
struct SomeType: Classes...
{
    SomeType() try {
        //...
    } catch (SomeTypeExp const & e) {
        throw e;
    } /*...*/
    catch (std::exception const & e) {
        throw make_some_expr(e);//return SomeTypeExp object
    }catch (...) {
        throw SomeTypeExp("Unknown");
    }
    //Other members
};
```

Для данного кода, какие бы исключения не вылетели при создании объекта, "наверх" вылетит исключение типа SomeTypeExp. Это значит, что "наверху" необходимо ловить и обрабатывать только его, а не все возможные типы исключений. Также Вы можете добавить сообщение в лог или произвести какие-то действия, однако обращаться к не статическим членам класса из данного блока нельзя, т.к. объект уже уничтожен и это хорошо видно, если исключение вылетело из делегирующего конструктора, после того, как успешно отработал не делегирующий.

Можете почитать больше о function-try-block для функций, деструкторов и конструкторов: http://pcdev.ru/function-try-block/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Единственное, не совсем согласен с фразой "объект уже уничтожен". Невозможно уничтожить то, чего нет

Comment: @Semerkin все созданные члены класса будут уже уничтоженные к моменту исполнения catch. А если не делегирующий конструктор нормально отработал, то объект уже создан и если делегирующий конструктор затем выбросит исключение, то будет вызван деструктор объекта. По ссылке, что я привел об этом написано. В качестве примера: http://rextester.com/DWLB20723

Answer (score 0):

Этот вид try-catch имеет специальное предназначение - он умеет перехватывать исключение в списке инициализации, то есть, чтобы обрабатывать исключения однотипно.

Но главная особенность этого try-catch - исключения в любом случае пробрасывается. Почему оно пробрасывается? потому что пока конструктор не отработал, объект считается не созданным и обращение к такому объекту - UB. А вызывающему коду нужно как то узнать, что объект не создан.

Comment: Это не объясняет необходимости try/catch в main. О чём, как я понял, как раз и спрашивает ТС.

Comment: необходимость try catch  в main - только одна - понять, что что то пошло не так и как то это обработать.

Comment: При всем уважении, не увидел объяснения необходимости trycatch в конструкторе. По первому абзацу: я перехвачу исключение из списка инициализации и во внешнем trycatch в main.  По второму абзацу - это особенность я знаю)

Comment: я же написал - "чтобы обрабатывать исключения однотипно". Во вторых, чтобы не размазывать логику обработки исключения.

Comment: Ну тоесть вы имеете ввиду что в catch конструктора могут прийти разные типы исключений, а передать наверх из catch мы можем что то одно своё?

Comment: это один с вариантов. Второй - можно логировать факт, что объект не создался, а уже вызывающий код будет логировать более абстрактную логику.

Answer (score 0):

Могу, наверное, сказать ересь но тут несколько вариантов:

1. Сработает исключение до создания объекта, например на выделение памяти (и до блока исключений в конструкторе не доходит)
2. В текущий реализации, этого нет, но catch(...) это наверное плохой вариант, catch лучше использовать специфицировано, на какие-то ожидаемые исключения, и если их нет - исключение пойдёт наверх, где об нём могут что то знать и правильно среагировать.

Comment: Вот, кстати, первый пункт объясняет наличие `try` в `main`. А ловля по `...` в `main` как раз подходящий случай, чтобы завершиться более-менее корректно. Правда, надо ещё уметь с других потоков исключения пробрасывать.

Comment: С других потоков позволяет async кинуть

Comment: До блока обработки исключения в конструкторе дело дойдёт если 1. Будет исключение в списке инициализации 2. В теле конструктора

Answer (score -2):

При возникновении исключения может возникнуть необходимость освободить уже выделенные ресурсы (когда часть ресурсов выделена, часть - еще нет). Обычно для этого используются RAII-обёртки над ресурсами, наподобие unique_ptr, но и так тоже можно.

Comment: забыли самое главное - при возникновении исключения в списке инициализации

Comment: @KoVadim про это уже написали, зачем повторяться?

Comment: если это просто выделение в теле конструктора, тогда и обычный try-catch поможет.

Comment: Ariox из catch обращаться к не статическим членам класса уже нельзя.

Comment: Поддерживаю предыдущий комментарий. В блоке trycatch конструктора не освободить память.